# Intellij not able to find image path in resources

Tags: css, intellij-idea, resources

This is a webapp(maven) where I am using css file(Perfmon.css) to point to a .png image.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP4NY.png)

CSS

```
background: url("../img/enlarge-to-left.png") 51px 69px no-repeat
```

Please note that *resources* directory is marked as **Resources Root**.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Doesn't it work when you run it? Is the issue in editor navigation?

Comment: I get a 404 as I see in the console output of the browser.